# combobox, how do i exclude blanks from list retrieved via listobject

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to apply data to a combobox, which works out great, except it also include filtered values.

1. i filter on field 1, filter by a number, there are several empty cells in this row, 
   those with empty cells in field1 i dont want to see this time.
2. I pupulate the databodyrange value from column 13 into the combobox list, however even when filtered correctly
   it also adds the rows i filtered away.

code..

```
Private Sub UserFrom_Initialize()
  Dim db As ListObject
  Set db = Worksheets("baseOfData").ListObjects("database")

  db.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
  Me.cmbTasks.List = db.ListColumns(13).DataBodyRange.Value
End Sub
```

I can solve it by running a for loop, and checking every cell before adding it
but that would kinda defeat the purpose of doing it all with 2 lines of code.

any suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> however even when filtered correctly it also adds the rows i filtered away.
>
> Me.cmbTasks.List = db.ListColumns(13).DataBodyRange.Value

That is because you are incorrectly doing it. You are referring to complete column and not the filtered range. Try this

```
Dim db As ListObject
Set db = Worksheets("baseOfData").ListObjects("database")

db.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
Me.cmbTasks.List = db.DataBodyRange.Columns(13).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
```

The next problem that you may face will be that it will show values from the first `Area` only if there are multiple areas.

[image]

To handle this, try

```
Dim db As ListObject
Dim aCell As Range, rngArea As Range

Set db = Worksheets("baseOfData").ListObjects("database")

db.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

'~~> Loop through each area
For Each rngArea In db.DataBodyRange.Columns(13).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
    '~~> Loop though each cell in the area
    For Each aCell In rngArea
        cmbTasks.AddItem aCell.Value
    Next aCell
Next rngArea
```

[image]

Comment: Aww, love it..  Thank that worked.

Even the first part, except that one excluded the last row, second part did the trick.
Thank you.

Comment: yes the right way would be to do it the 2nd way. I have updated the post with screenshots so that you can see how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not a little simpler (if iteration is an option):

```
Dim db As ListObject, cel As Range

Set db = Worksheets("baseOfData").ListObjects("database")
For Each cel In db.DataBodyRange.Columns(13).Cells
    If cel.EntireRow.Hidden <> True Then
        cmbTasks.AddItem cel.value
    End If
Next
```

Would you like to do some modifications on the table, according to selected combo value? If yes, the real row number associated to each combo value must be memorized. In a hidden column of the combo, for instance (using `cel.Row`).